# Can we do ESB testing through Apache Jmeter?

Tags: oracle, jmeter, esb

i want to do Oracle ESB Performance testing through Jmeter. Can this be done through Apache Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Service_Bus):

> **Connectivity**
>
> - SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 invocations services
> - REST Restful web services
> - JMS
> - Websphere MQ
> - Adapter services
>
>   - File/FTP adapter service
>   - Database adapter service

All above can be tested using JMeter:

1. [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)
2. [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
3. [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter)
4. [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html)

Going forward you need to be more specific as your question is too broad as Oracle ESB is quite a big solution and different aspects will require different approaches.